# Spark Structured Streaming query: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Checkpoint delete only option?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I get

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: There are [13] sources in the checkpoint offsets and now there are [16] sources requested by the query. Cannot continue.
```

This happens because the streaming query takes unioned DF and number of sources in the union changed.

My question: Is deleting the checkpoint and have the query read from earliest the only option for the query to not die?